# Track Language Badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, tag-badges, badge-progress

I may have missed this, but I want to track my progress towards the C# gold badge.

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible in the badge-tracker.

1. Why is this?
2. Is this a feature worthy of consideration?

Comment: I just did a sanity check on my profile and I'm already tracking the gold Python badge (and I'm shockingly close to getting it - how the hell'd that happen??), so I don't know if this is an issue.  Can you show pictures of your badge tracker and what you're seeing when you attempt to do this?

Comment: You can track it in the reputation section. There you can change from privilege tracking to badge tracking and select language badges. Or are you focused on the badges section?

Comment: Tag tracking is in place of privilege tracking; you can have one, but not both

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gpjA.png

Answer (score 4):

Language badges can be tracked within the reputation section:

[image]

To get the badge tracking at that place you can change from privilege tracking:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I missed that... thanks